# React Tanstack useQuery showing 'pause' status on every query

Tags: reactjs, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

All of mine queries showing the 'paused' status.

Even though the 'enable' flag is true.

[Here is the screen of how devtools look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/248pe.png)

and the hook that calling the query

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const getWordInfo = async (word: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API}/api/conjugations/${word.trim()}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  if (!data.isSuccess) throw Error(data.message || "Server Error");

  return data;
};

export const useConjugation = (word: string) => {
  const {
    data: wordInfo,
    isFetching,
    isError,
    isSuccess
  } = useQuery<any>(["conjugations", word], async () => await getWordInfo(word), {
    enabled: !!word,
    retry: true,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false
  });

  return { data: wordInfo, isSuccess, isFetching, isError };
};
```

backend working properly, tested it with postman.
'word' argument is passing properly, so the 'enable' flag is true (also seen at the screenshot)

Tried to play around the enabled flag, but that doesn't help. Also updated the package to the latest stable, also no luck

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I seem to be having this issue now too. It also appears to only be in Chrome desktop and not on chrome mobile or safari desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, couldn't get past the login query. Restarting my machine fixed the problem!

Comment: Had the same problem! The queries were all paused, whatever the target: whether on localhost:3000, on my staging server and my prod server! I find this a bit scary: difficult to explain to an end user: you need to reboot your machine for my app to work, although all other sites work great! 

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/network-mode#devtools), this is because you do not have a network connection.